# Intellij run button is greyed out

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I haven't used IntelliJ in a while and I started working on a project and when I went to run it and I realized that the run button is greyed out and consequentially I can't press it. If I go into the run menu on the top and click run it opens a little box to edit the run configurations. I tried to mess around this but every time I changed it the only thing that changed was the error code. I tried to reinstall IntelliJ and I have reinstalled the most recent version of java and the most recent JDK. I have also opened and created multiple projects still to no avail. I Don't know how much this helps but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxA7e.jpg) is a picture of it.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose without knowing what run configuration(s) you tried to add. The project needs a JDK and it needs at least one run configuration so it know what to run.

Comment: What error codes do you get? Can you share a screenshot of the run configuration you are trying to run and the errors that you get in the console?